# etcd - is the leader node automatically and dynamically elected? newbie question

Tags: etcd

It's been about several hours since I am actively looking into `etcd` and I have a newbie question:

Is the leader node *dynamically* and *automatically* elected or the "human" operator of the cluster must take action?

If **yes**, then what are the conditions that must be met in order to begin the election of a new leader node?

If **no**, then what should be done?

Comment: it is automatic. If one of the masters goes down, for any reason, another one is getting elected. Again, automatic.

Comment: some more details? what are the conditions defining "master is down state"?

Comment: Check [this](https://learnk8s.io/etcd-kubernetes). Related to k8s, but in general described as well. I hope it'll be enough